# Vertical scrolling slides with mousewheel

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to recreate the vertical scrolling from this page: http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/

Is there a library that will implement this (with jquery is ok).  Particularly, I want to override the mouse wheel and keyboard so that scrolling down will smoothly jump to the next section and scrolling up will smoothly jump to the previous section.

Comment: did you look at the source code of that page (view page source) ?

Comment: I did, it looks like everything is compiled, so I can't tell what's going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnePageScroll may be what you're looking for: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/09/18/onepagescroll-js-creating-an-apples-iphone-5s-website/

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at `fullPage.js`, simple but quite powerful. You can even link it with a menu and use landscape scrolling too. Also, it works in IE8 and IE9 not like **onePageScroll** which only works with IE 10 and modern browsers.

- [Demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage)
- [Website](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like http://github.com/stephband/jparallax.

also try http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/